# Error Code: 1054, Unknown column on a simple input

Tags: mysql, sql

I keep getting an error code when I try to input data into a table. the table and input schema are below. Am I doing something wrong? I feel like I have don't this before, many times, without fault.

```
CREATE database bamazon;

DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS bamazon;

USE bamazon;

CREATE TABLE product (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  product_name VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
  department_name VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
  price DECIMAL (10, 4) NOT NULL,
  stock_quantity INT (4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO product ( product_name, department_name, price, stock_quantity)
VALUES ("simpsonwave_vol_1", "trap_vidz", 29.99, 100);
```

Error code: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'simpsonwave_vol_1' in 'field list'

Comment: values should be wrap with `single quote` **not** double quotes. eg. `VALUES ('simpsonwave_vol_1', 'trap_vidz', 29.99, 100)`

Comment: That was it! thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use single quotes instead of double `INSERT INTO product ( product_name, department_name, price, stock_quantity)
VALUES ('simpsonwave_vol_1', 'trap_vidz', 29.99, 100);`

Answer (score 0):

Place `DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS bamazon;` line on top. The code will be like:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS bamazon;

CREATE database bamazon;

USE bamazon;

CREATE TABLE product (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  product_name VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
  department_name VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
  price DECIMAL (10, 4) NOT NULL,
  stock_quantity INT (4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO product ( product_name, department_name, price, stock_quantity)
VALUES ("simpsonwave_vol_1", "trap_vidz", 29.99, 100);
```